# Splitting a string on a list of strings in Go

Tags: string, go, split

Is it possible to split not just on one string but also a slice of strings? I.e.

```
strings.Split("Dogs and Cats are Great", "and"))
```

But instead of using one string, a slice of strings as so:

```
strings.Split("Dogs and Cats are Great", []string{"and", "are"}))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression: http://play.golang.org/p/vCRCv4rt7s

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`and|are`)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.Split("Dogs and Cats are Great", -1))
```

Comment: This seems like an elegant solution. I am wondering, is there a way to split before the word rather than replacing it on the split?

Comment: @JamesMilner: Please show what you mean by "split before the word".

Comment: I.e. return "Dogs", "and Cats", "are Great" rather than "Dogs", "Cats", "Great"

Comment: @JamesMilner: I would find the indexes of the matches (using something like `FindAllStringIndex`), and slice the string based on that.

Comment: I think that's the best solution. Thanks for your help.